# Calculating distance in months between two occurrences in a data set

Tags: r, data.table

This follows a question I asked lately on the forum (the first part was brilliantly solved by a forum member who advised me to post a new question for this one) but now I have the following issue and I hope you may help me: I have a huge database (which I cannot disclose) but is it is structured as follows:

5 million observations
4 variables of of interest:
Code ID Buy
Code ID Sell
Date
New : if there was no transaction before between the buyer and the seller, this is the first occurrence in line i so the variable new takes the value 1
Distance : the distance in months between the two last occurences of new = 1 provided Code_ID_Buy is the same for the two rows

I would like another variable called distance with Distancelastr1, which does the same thing as "distance" but also for the lines where new = 0:

A reduced sample would look like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,3,4,5),
  Amount = rnorm(21,mean=100,sd=20),
  Code_ID_Buy = c("100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","102D","102D","102D"),
  Code_ID_Sell = c("98C","99C","98C","99C","98C","99C","96V","98C","99C","96V","98C","99C","96V","94D","98C","99C","96V","94D","25A","25A","25A")
)


Data$new<-0

setDT(Data)[order(Month, Code_ID_Buy, Code_ID_Sell), new := {
  r <- rowid(Code_ID_Buy, Code_ID_Sell)
  +(r==1L)
}]

Data[Month==1L, new:=0L]

Data[new==1L, distance := .SD[.SD, on=.(Code_ID_Buy, Month<Month), mult="last",
                              by=.EACHI, i.Month - x.Month]$V1]

Data$Distancewithlastr1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,NA,1,2)
Data$LastRelationshipseller = c("98C","98C","98C","98C","98C","98C","98C","96V","96V","96V","96V","96V","96V","96V","94D","94D","94D","94D",NA,"25A","25A")
View(Data)
```

Here Distancelastr1 should take value "NA" if month = 1 and no "new = 1" has been recorded since month 1. If there is a new = 1 for a given buyer let us say for month x, then Distancewithlastr1 in month i calculates month i - month x.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: @chinsoon12 thank you that solves most of the issue indeed at least on the sample version. For rows 7 and 14, the logic is that even though it is a new relationship I wish to calculate the distance with the last new relationship before this one. Is that possible ?

Comment: @chinsoon12 this is a mistake on my end when building the database, row 19 should be NA thank you for noticing.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thank you a lot, this seems to work. Can you tell me how you find these formulas ? I really would like to learn R by myself but I just do not seem to understand the mechanisms at work...

Comment: You must start with base R first. Go through the manuals, function documentation, tutorials, stackoverflow, practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
Data[, dlr := if (k>0L) rleid(Month) - 1L, .(Code_ID_Buy, k=cumsum(new))][, 
    dlr := fifelse(new==1L, shift(dlr), dlr), Code_ID_Buy]
```